# How to disable phpStorm auto-completing $this- into $this->

Tags: phpstorm

As per the title.
phpstorm 2020.3.2

Within quotes in a class method, when I type `$this-`  phpstorm automatically adds a `>`, thus every time I'm ending up with `$this->>method`

How the heck do I disable this?
I've gone through the "smart keys" and "code completion" sections and I just can't find this.

Very annoying feature. :(

Answer (score 1):

> Within quotes in a class method, when I type `$this-` PhpStorm automatically adds a `>`, thus every time I'm ending up with `$this->>method`

Works fine for me: PhpStorm eats the extra `>` just fine.

```php
<?php

class Cls_B
{
    public function item()
    {
        echo "{$this->}";
    }
}
```

**Anyway:** you cannot disable this behaviour. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-30364

**P.S.** A possible workaround: create a custom Live Template that would expand `$t` (or whatever abbreviation you want) into `$this->` ... so you just type `$t[TAB]` and have `$this->` -- no need for pressing any of the `->` keys at all.

Comment: Thanks mate.  I reckon I'll just drop this phpStorm thingo and go back to phpEd. 
The more I use it the more annoying & unnecessary fluff surfaces. :(  I already had to work around a couple of useless "features".

Comment: @SteveHorvath It's up to you. Perhaps you have not tried it for long enough. I personally do not have any major issues with this IDE as well as not getting annoyed by how `$this->` completion works .. because for me it just works.